# Find unique combination of column values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic, combinations

I am trying to find all the unique possible combinations of values in a column using SQL.

I have a table with a maximum of 5 values in a single column: something like:

```
a,
b,
c,
d,
e
```

I need help with a my SQL Server code to find only the UNIQUE combinations of the values which would be:

```
ab, ac, ad, ae, bc, bd, be, cd, ce, de, abc, acd, ade...
```

Currently I am using the below code to find the 1,2 value combinations. The table name is `my_table` and the column with the values is `non_unique_column`.

```
select 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY '' ORDER BY concat(col1,col2,col3)) [index]
    ,* into final_comb_out 
from (select 
            non_unique_column col1, NULL as col2,NULL AS COL3 FROM my_table 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(t1.non_unique_column, t2.non_unique_column) AS value1,
                GREATEST(t1.non_unique_column, t2.non_unique_column) AS value2
                ,NULL AS value3    
        FROM my_table t1
CROSS JOIN my_table t2
WHERE t1.non_unique_column <> t2.non_unique_column
```

The issue with this code is that the LEAST and GREATEST function are not supported by the client system and cannot be included.

I would very much appreciate code that could help me out here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion:

```
WITH RecursiveCombination AS (
    SELECT 
        CAST(non_unique_column AS VARCHAR(255)) AS combination,
        non_unique_column AS last_char
    FROM my_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        CAST(rc.combination + mt.non_unique_column AS VARCHAR(255)) AS combination,
        mt.non_unique_column AS last_char
    FROM my_table mt
    JOIN RecursiveCombination rc ON mt.non_unique_column > rc.last_char
)
SELECT combination
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT combination, LEN(combination) as len_comb
    FROM RecursiveCombination
    WHERE LEN(combination) > 1
) t
ORDER BY t.len_comb, t.combination;
```

**Output:**

| combination |
| --- |
| ab |
| ac |
| ad |
| ae |
| bc |
| bd |
| be |
| cd |
| ce |
| de |
| abc |
| abd |
| abe |
| acd |
| ace |
| ade |
| bcd |
| bce |
| bde |
| cde |
| abcd |
| abce |
| abde |
| acde |
| bcde |
| abcde |

Try it out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/32dae/1).

Answer (score 1):

The fixed max length of the source table allows a plain join solution, e.g.

```
declare @x char(1)=char((select ascii(max(non_unique_column))+1 from my_table)); 
with tplus as (
  select * from my_table union select @x
)
select comb
from (
    select replace(
       cast(t1.non_unique_column AS VARCHAR(5)) 
          + t2.non_unique_column 
          + t3.non_unique_column 
          + t4.non_unique_column
          + t5.non_unique_column
                    ,@x,'') comb
    from my_table t1
    join my_table t2 on t1.non_unique_column < t2.non_unique_column
    join tplus t3 on t2.non_unique_column < t3.non_unique_column
    join tplus t4 on t3.non_unique_column < t4.non_unique_column or t4.non_unique_column = @x
    join tplus t5 on t4.non_unique_column < t5.non_unique_column or t5.non_unique_column = @x
) t
order by len(comb), comb
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0TELj7lE)

Still I'd prefer a recursive one as Sash Sinha suggested.